# How to write a unix console?

Tags: unix, console

I must embedd the shell of an interpreter language (most likely it will be python) inside my application. So i need a console widget in my GUI toolkit. I want to write this from ground up myself.

I know that i must start the process with pipes redirecting the standard input/output/error to my console widget. I have to set the environment variable TERM=vt100 and send a SIGWINCH signal whenever i resize my terminal.

For the output of the program i have to check the octet stream for vt100 control characters as explained here [VT100 commands](http://braun-home.net/michael/info/misc/VT100_commands.htm).

This sounds to be easy and a nice weekend hack.

But what do i do about the input? Who is responsible for echoing the characters and the line mode editing?

Do i miss something else which is serious?

Answer (score 1):

To control the input in console, you have set it to canonical mode. Please check this like link, it may help you:
[Canonical vs. non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input)