# How would I go about, using the scanner class, taking in one character and then continuing to display the next random character for the user to enter?

Tags: java

My intentions are to show a letter and have the user type the letter, while after they have hit the corresponding key (whether it's right or wrong) it is to then display the next key. I can only make this happen, at the moment, after pressing the key and then pressing the enter key following so that it finishes the scanner.next() method. Any way that I could automate the enter key so that I could make it scan in the character letter and then automatically continue to the next randomly generated character? Let me know if there needs to be clarification on this.

```
//some initialized code here
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
int letterToDisplay = rand.nextInt(26)
System.out.printf("%s\r\n", letters[letterToDispaly]);

**String inputLetter = scanner.next();**

if(intputLetter.exquals(letters[letterToDisplay]))
{
letterCounter(letterToDisplay);
}
}
//some methods etc. here
```

Thanks,

Kyle P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to read user input from a console character-by-character using the standard API; for example the Unix terminal is by default line-buffered which means that the OS does not transfer characters into the application's buffer until the user hits enter. [You can't do it even from standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327942/non-buffering-stdin-reading).

You need to run code specific to the OS and terminal to achieve this, ideally wrapped in a library, like the ones discussed here: [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

A better option is using a graphical user interface. It's not the 1970s anymore ;)