# Output behaviour of scanf and printf in C (Eclipse Console)

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, scanf

Excuse me if this might be painfully obvious, but I've not found an answer to this so far. I just started learning some C basics after mostly working with Java so far.

I've tried to follow [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-input-output) tutorial and am currently very confused with how printf and scanf behave in the Eclipse console.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char character;
    printf("Enter a character: ");

    scanf("%c", &character);

    printf("Character: %c",character);
    return 0;
}
```

**What I'm expecting to happen, based on the linked tutorial:**

`Enter a character: _`

I'm expecting this line to be printed to the console and then wait for my input where I put `_` as a placeholder, before then printing `Character: _`. This behaviour is how I'd expect it in Java.

**What actually happens:**

On running my code, the console stays completely empty. At first I spent 2 hours thinking the program was simply not executing. Luckily I then noticed that the empty console was simply my prompt to give my user input. Once I input a character and press enter, the printf's are written into the console like so:

```
a
Enter a character: 
Character: a
```

Is this behaviour normal and my expectations for the behaviour are just plain wrong? If so, how would I go about realizing my desired behaviour of first being presented with the prompt to input a character?

Comment: Why are you expecting the input cursor to remain on the same line after printing a newline character (`\n`)? Perhaps the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4327942/1679849) will help.

Comment: @r3mainer Oh my bad, I added the newline character while trying things out, I wasn't expecting it to ignore the newline character. Thank you anyway for the resource!

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks, that did it! So you're saying this is an IDE specific behaviour? Feel free to post your comment again as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: No, it's not so much IDE specific. The reason is the output buffering of the terminal, many IDEs are line-buffered.

Comment: @thebusybee Alright thanks for the reply.