# read only 1 character in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is std::iostream buffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957721/how-is-stdiostream-buffered)

This might sound ridiculous, but how can I read one char from cin in c++ (NOT until enter is pressed, just one character)?
I've tried operator >>, get(), getchar(), but all of them reads a whole line.

Comment: All of the methods that you specify read one character from `std::cin`. That character isn't made available from the O/S, however, until ENTER is pressed.

Comment: What OS are you using? As Rob said, the OS holds the input until <enter>. To get a keyboard event when it happens, you need an OS-specific library.

Comment: @Robᵩ So what you say is that it is not possible to read only one char? All the other languages I know have a function for that.

Comment: @Dave - It's not a language problem, it is system specific. I you run your program on a mainframe, the *terminal* will not send the input until you press Enter. C++ cannot do anything about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [_getche() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kswce429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does what you want.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't ask for portability and he states in his comments above he's using Win7.  Also, as Adam Shiemke and Rob pointed out, to get a keyboard event you're going to need an OS-specific function.

Answer (score 3):

`cin` is buffered input.  You want "unbuffered" input.  It can be different on different platforms, unless you work directly with files.

Something like this might help:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3329/

[EDIT], Remember that use of "buffered" v. "un-buffered" is a design decision, and both are legitimate.  The "default" for "buffered-input" on `cin` makes a lot of sense, as the user will "backspace" to correct the input-line, and you don't want that "clutter" feeding your program.  (And, in general, "buffered-input" like from files can be much more efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

While this is OS specific, in UNIX-like operating systems you can use the termios interface to disable input buffering on the terminal by putting it in non-canonical mode:

```
termios t;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t);
t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
```

See [termios(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) for more details.