# When does scanf start and stop scanning?

Tags: c, io, buffer, scanf

It seems `scanf` begins scanning the input when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, and I want to verify this with the code below (I eliminated error checking and handling for simplicity).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* disable buffering */
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    int number;

    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("number: %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Here comes another problem, after I disable input buffering (just to verify the result; I know I should next-to-never do that in reality in case it interferes the results), the output is (note the extra prompt):

```
$ ./ionbf
12(space)(enter)
number: 12
$
$
```

which is different from the output when input buffering is enabled (no extra prompt):

```
$ ./iofbf
12(space)(enter)
number: 12
$
```

It seems the new line character is consumed when buffer enabled. I tested on two different machines, one with gcc 4.1.2 and bash 3.2.25 installed, the other with gcc 4.4.4 and bash 4.1.5, and the result is the same on both.

The problems are:

1. How to explain the different behaviors when input buffering is enabled and disabled?
2. Back to the original problem, when does `scanf` begin scanning user input? The moment a character is entered? Or is it buffered until a line completes?

Comment: What extra prompt? Your code is not printing it! This is a typical user error

Comment: @AdrianCornish If a user error, how should I correct it?

Comment: @AdrianCornish- I don't know whether your comment is correct or not but the "Change the user!" comment is epic :-D

Comment: @Adrian you are wrong, but your comment is -- wrong, too, but attractive :D +1

Comment: Show me the line of code that prints the $'s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question — long-winded answer.  In case of doubt, I'm describing what I think happens on Unix; I leave Windows to other people.  I think the behaviour would be similar, but I'm not sure.

When you use `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`, you force the `stdin` stream to read one character at a time using the `read(0, buffer, 1)` system call.  When you run with `_IOFBF` or `_IOLBF`, then the code managing the stream will attempt to read many more bytes at a time (up to the size of the buffer you provide if you use `setvbuf()`, or `BUFSIZ` if you don't).  These observations plus the space in your input are key to explaining what happens.  I'm assuming your terminal is in normal or canonical input mode — see [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/358381#358381) for a discussion of that.

You are correct that the terminal driver does not make any characters available until you type return.  This allows you to use backspace etc to edit the line as you type it.

When you hit return, the kernel has 4 characters available to send to any program that wants to read them: <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>.

In the case where you are *not* using `_IONBF`, those 4 characters are all read at once into the standard I/O buffer for `stdin` by a call such as `read(0, buffer, BUFSIZ)`.  The `scanf()` then collects the <kbd>1</kbd>, the <kbd>2</kbd> and the <kbd>space</kbd> characters from the buffer, and puts back the space into the buffer. (Note that the kernel has passed all four characters to the program.)  The program prints its output and exits.  The shell resumes, prints a prompt and waits for some more input to be available — but there won't be any input available until the user types another <kbd>return</kbd>, possibly (usually) preceded by some other characters.

In the case where you *are* using `_IONBF`, the program reads the characters one at a time.  It makes a `read()` call to get one character and gets the <kbd>1</kbd>; it makes another `read()` call and gets the <kbd>2</kbd>; it makes another `read()` call and gets the <kbd>space</kbd> character.  (Note that the kernel still has the <kbd>return</kbd> ready and waiting.)  It doesn't need the space to interpret the number, so it puts it back in its pushback buffer (there is guaranteed to be space for at least one byte in the pushback buffer), ready for the next standard I/O read operation, and returns.  The program prints its output and exits.  The shell resumes, prints a prompt, and tries to read a new command from the terminal.  The kernel obliges by returning the newline that is waiting, and the shell says "Oh, that's an empty command" and gives you another prompt.

You can demonstrate this is what happens by typing <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> to your (`_IONBF`) program.  When you do that, your program reads the value 12 and the 'x', leaving 'ps' and the newline to be read by the shell, which will then execute the `ps` command (without echoing the characters that it read), and then prompt again.

You could also use `truss` or `strace` or a similar command to track the system calls that are executed by your program to see the veracity of what I suggest happens.

Comment: Thanks for that. I completely missed the `(space)` in the question, and that derailed my (now deleted) answer. Now I don't have to wonder where I went wrong! +1

Comment: Why Will It Read 'X' ?

Comment: @SurajJain: It will read the `x` because it doesn't know it has finished processing the `%d` conversion until it reads something (like `x`) that cannot be part of the number.  But when the process reads the `x`, that `x` cannot be read by any other process — so the shell finds the `ps` and newline in the input stream and reads those characters and executes the command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But, Wont It Return Back To The Buffer?

Comment: @SurajJain: Which buffer?  There isn't a buffer that's shared between the program that's shown in the question and the shell — so there's no way for the process to make the `x` available to the shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir , When You say "t doesn't need the space to interpret the number, so it puts it back in its pushback buffer (there is guaranteed to be space for at least one byte in the pushback buffer), ready for the next standard I/O read operation, and returns." Which Buffer is it.

Comment: That buffer is the standard I/O buffer for `stdin` in the process.  But that standard I/O buffer is in user-space memory (as opposed to kernel memory); it goes away when the program dies.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So, Every Program That Starts Get its Standard I/O Buffer?

Comment: And Sir, I really like your answers and your nature, You really help a lot, and know a lot, also i have seen plenty of question that were edited by you, to make it clear, you really give a lot of work here.