# Why scanf("%d", [...]) does not consume '\n'? while scanf("%c") does?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217074/parsing-input-with-scanf-in-c), I saw this statement in the accepted answer:

> Most of the conversion specifiers skip leading whitespace including newlines but `%c` does not.

For me it is not clear the rationale under this different behaviors, I would have expected a uniform one (e.g. always skipping or never).

I came into this kind of problem with a piece of C code like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){

    char ch;
    int actualNum;

    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &actualNum);
    // getchar();

    printf("Insert a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Swapping the two `scanf`s solves the problem, as well as the (commented) `getchar`, otherwise the `'\n'` of the first insertion would be consumed by the second `scanf` with `%c`. I tested on gcc both on linux and windows, the behavior is the same:

> gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)
>   Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

So my question is: Why does `%d` and `%c` behave differently w.r.t. `'\n'` in `scanf`?

Comment: The `"%c"` format is used to read a single character, even if it is a space. How else would you do that?

Comment: You could use `scanf(" %c", &ch);` (with a space before the %).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926268/when-does-scanf-start-and-stop-scanning

Comment: Not sure what your question actually is.  Please edit your posting to provide a specific question.

Comment: Note that behavior is dependent on the buffering mode applied to `stdin`. On a terminal, it defaults to line-buffered. That means in effect that input is provided in bursts, as signaled by newline. Neither call to `scanf` will even see any characters until the line is terminated, **but the newline is included in the input**. If `stdin` is redirected from a file, the buffering is different and the behavior will appear to change.

Comment: @RichardChambers: thank you, the question was not explicitly stated, I edited it hoping it is more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [horse's mouth](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function
>
> ...
> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
> ﬁrst non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
> be read. The directive never fails.
> ...
> 7 A directive that is a conversion speciﬁcation deﬁnes a set of matching input sequences, as
> described below for each speciﬁer. A conversion speciﬁcation is executed in the following steps:
> 8 Input white-space characters (as speciﬁed by the `isspace` function) are skipped, **unless
> the speciﬁcation includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` speciﬁer**.
> <sup>284)</sup>
> 9 An input item is read from the stream, unless the speciﬁcation includes an `n` speciﬁer. **An
> input item is deﬁned as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
> any speciﬁed ﬁeld width and which is, or is a preﬁx of, a matching input sequence.**
> <sup>285)</sup>
> The ﬁrst character, if any, after the input item remains unread. If the length of the input
> item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless
> end-of-ﬁle, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which
> case it is an input failure.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>284) These white-space characters are not counted against a speciﬁed ﬁeld width.
>
> 285) fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream. Therefore, some sequences
> that are acceptable to strtod, strtol, etc., are unacceptable to fscanf.</sup>

Emphasis added by me.

Whitespace is not part of a valid integer string, so it makes sense for the `%d` conversion specifier to skip any leading whitespace.  However, whitespace may be valid on its own, so it makes sense for the `%c` conversion specifier to *not* skip it.

Per clause 5 above, if you put a blank space in the format string prior to the `%c` directive, all leading whitespace will be skipped:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Answer (score 13):

It is consistent behavior, you're just thinking about it wrong. ;)

```
scanf("%c", some_char); // reads a character from the key board.
scanf("%d", some_int);  // reads an integer from the key board.
```

So if I do this:

```
printf("Insert a character: ");
scanf("%c", &ch);                // if I enter 'f'. Really I entered 'f' + '\n'
                                 // scanf read the first char and left the '\n'
printf("Insert a number: ");
scanf("%d", &actualNum);      // Now scan if is looking for an int, it sees the '\n'
                              // still, but that's not an int so it waits for the 
                              // the next input from stdin
```

It's not that it's consuming the newline on its own in this case. Try this instead:

```
char ch;
char ch2;
printf("Insert a character: ");
scanf("%c", &ch);
printf("Insert another character: ");
scanf("%c", &ch2);
```

It will "skip" the second `scanf()` because it reads in the `'\n'` at that time. `scanf()` is consistent and you MUST consume that `'\n'` if you're going to use it correctly.

Comment: thank you very much, even if your answers were equivalently clear the "horse's mouth" of the accepted one was an extra value for me!

Comment: This logic doesn't really work; if `scanf("%d"` sees a letter then it doesn't skip it and wait for an int still.

Comment: @Matt Yes, you are correct. I was trying to simplify the answer for the OP and I think I over simplified it, I changed it slightly to remove the error.. but I still need come up with better wording

Answer (score 2):

It is because whitespace can never be an integer, but whitespace is made up of characters. If you specifically want a character try something like

```
scanf("%c", &ch );
while(isspace(c))
    scanf("%c" , &ch);
```

Or use `!isalnum()` if you want to allow only letters and numbers or `!isalpha()` for only letters.

Answer (score -2):

I'm no expert, but i've found that doing:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

after every scanf helps..

Such as:

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: The behavior of `fflush` is not defined for input streams; what it does for any particular system is not guaranteed to be correct or repeatable.  Do not use `fflush` to clear the input stream.

Comment: Ok... I get it. fflush used in this manner has undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBode What do you suggest can be used to clear any pending bytes in the input stream?

Comment: @SreenikethanI: For text input, call `getchar()` or `fgetc()` in a loop until you see a newline or `EOF`: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );`.