# C: scanf() inside a loop

Tags: c, loops, scanf

This program doesn't seem to accept input at every iteration of the while loop, when ideally it should.However when I replace the %c parameter of the scanf() function with %d ( i.e an integer input rather than a char input) it seems to just work absolutely fine, which input accepted for every iteration of the while loop. Why do I see this discrepancy ?

```
int main()
{
    char grade;
    int i=0;

    while(i<10){
        printf("Enter ur grade\n");
        scanf("%c", &grade);
        switch(grade){
            case 'A' : printf("U R THE BEST\n");
                       break;
            case 'B' : printf("U R VERY GOOD DUDE...\n");
                       break;
            case 'C' : printf("U R GOOD DUDE...\n");
                       break;
            case 'D' : printf("U R Not good DUDE...\n");
                       break;
            case 'E' : printf("U R WORST DUDE...\n");
                       break;
            default  : printf("U r AWESOME...\n");
                       break;
        }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and the output you get?

Comment: scanf doesn't remove newline from input buffer. many dups on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275417/why-scanfd-does-not-consume-n-while-scanfc-does (not really dupe but solution to your problem)

Comment: Every time you input a char (you are actually inputting two chars), there's a newline (`\n`) char left in the input stream, which is consumed in the next iteration.  You need to clear it with `getchar()` or similar techniques.

Comment: add fflush(stdin); after scanf

Comment: Your braces don't balance. Also what's wrong with `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`?

Answer (score -1):

Add a space before the `%c` of the `scanf`. This is done to remove all blanks from the `stdin` before scanning a character. `scanf` does not take the `\n`(enter key) character after entering a character and leaves it in the buffer which is taken when `scanf` is called again.

Another thing: you forgot to put one `}` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

try this : put a space before `%c` it is because it stores `\n` too.

```
 scanf(" %c", &grade);
```