# Scanf is not scanning %c character but skips the statement, why is that?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, scanf, dev-c++

I wrote a program using switch case statement and asked for a char for input but it does not ask for the char in the console window but skips it completely

```
int main() 
{
    float a, b, ans;
    char opr;

    printf("\nGIVE THE VALUES OF THE TWO NUMBERS\n");
    scanf(" %f %f",&a,&b);


    printf("\nGIVE THE REQUIRED OPERATOR\n");   

    //no display(echo) on the screen
    //opr = getch();
    //displays on the screen
    //opr = getche();

    scanf("%c",&opr);

    switch(opr)
    {
        case '+' :
            ans = a+b;
            printf("%f", ans);
            break;          
        case '-' :
            ans = a-b;
            printf("%f", ans);
            break;          
        case '*' :
            ans = a*b;
            printf("%f", ans);
            break;          
        case '/' :
            ans = a/b;
            printf("%f", ans);
            break;
        case '%' :
            ans = (int)a % (int)b;
            printf("%f", ans);
            break;
        default :
            printf("\nGIVE A VALID OPRATOR\n");

    }

    system("pause");        
    return 0;
```

but when i put a space before `%c` in the second `scanf` it works someone was telling something about a whitespace which i found confusing

He said the second `scanf` is taking the value of `\n` as a character and if i put a space before `%c` in the second `scanf` isn't that a character and doesn't it take the space as the character?

But in this program it does not take the `\n` as the character

```
int main() 
{
    char a;
    printf("\ngive a char\n");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%c",a);

    return 0;
}
```

This is really confusing can any on help me i want to learn what is wrong.

Comment: That is probably it reads in the 'newline' character that you enter after inserting the two numbers. The input works like a buffer queue. It lines up characters. In this case, you told it to read the first number into &a , skip whatever in between, read second number into &b, then read the next character. Since after entering the number into &b, im guessing you hit 'ENTER', so it will read 'newline' into &opr. A quick way to fix this is to add another line of 'scanf("%c",&opr);' immediately after your scanf operation line.

Comment: Put a space before `%c` in the second `scanf`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275417/why-scanfd-does-not-consume-n-while-scanfc-does

Comment: Don't use `scanf`. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: so when i put enter before what does it do does it skip the newline as a character and neglects the enter before %c and waits for the actual character that the user wants to give? and can you tell me what actually is a whitespace in programming ?

Comment: Whitespace is any "empty" character. Like space and tab. So `scanf(" %c", &opr)`.

Comment: White-space characters are space, horizontal tab, new-line,
vertical tab, and form-feed, according to "6.4 Lexical elements" in [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @Washington Guedes If you use `scanf("%s", a);`, change `a`'s type to `char[2];`. also, `scanf("%1s", a);`, which is with reduced buffer overrun risk is better.

Comment: @MikeCAT. You are right, I didn't know that. _http://ideone.com/73DgOh_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you use scanf with this format :

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

it leaves a newline which will be consumed in the next iteration.
Th last program that you mentioned have only one "scanf". try to use another scanf. you will get the same problem.

so to avoid white spaces you have to write :

```
 scanf(" %c",&opr);
```

the space before the format string tells scanf to ignore white spaces. Or its better to use

```
getchar();
```

It will consume all your newline

Comment: thanks great explanation and what is the difference between getche() and getchar()

Comment: If you really want to clear your concept follow this link :                                      http://www.c-lang.thiyagaraaj.com/archive/c-blog/use-of-getch-getche-and-getchar-in-c

Comment: i would really do but it is not allowing me i just came to the website like few min before asking the question it say you have to have reputation 15 something

Comment: @psraganvesh : No probs...wlcm to the stcakoverflow !!

Comment: thanks brother.....☺

Answer (score 1):

The second program do take the `\n` as the character.
Maybe you simply didn't input `\n` before inputting other characters.

[example ( `%c` in printf is changed to `%d` to make it clear)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rn0IjQi7TVRUYb00)

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Why did you remove my quotation and made it as plain text?

Comment: Simple text is not required quotation until you are including error, and code requires only indentation.

Comment: Why simply deleting the unneeded quotation didn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are leaving the `\n` entered after the numbers unconsumed and then is read by the second `scanf()`.
If you check the value in `opr` you'll see it's '\n'.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding fflush(stdin) before scanf.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` wil cause undefined behavior because `stdin` is an input stream.