# Scanning a char array after scanning an integer in C

Tags: c

I'm a newbie in programming. It is confusing me when I taking input of a char array after scanning an integer. It is not working properly.
The code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[30];
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%[^\n]",a);
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d",x,a,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is following:
[image]

Comment: And this is why you check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: I can't understand this.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.6.2 The fscanf function Returns 16 The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf is not scanning %c character but skips the statement, why is that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643397/scanf-is-not-scanning-c-character-but-skips-the-statement-why-is-that)

Comment: Unless an answer recommends checking the return value from `scanf()`, it is not that good an answer.  Save yourself time 1) always check the return value of an input function.  Read documents to know what return value is expected.  2) better to use `fgets()` than `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the `white spaces`.After `scanf("%d",&x);` the last entered  `'\n'` character is taken and saved the string `a` of `scanf("%[^\n]",a)`.

---

To avoid this give space in `scanf()` statement

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",a);//give a space
```

> **Why to give a space?**
>
> By giving a space,the compiler consumes the `'\n'` character or any
>   other white space (`'\0'`,`'\t'` or `' '` ) from the previous `scanf()`

---

your **code** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[30];
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf(" %[^\n]",a);//give a space
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d",x,a,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. please upvote my question if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` with `scanf(" %99[^\n]", a);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[30];
    int x,y;

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%s",a);            // get char array without inputing space
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", a);    // get char array, allowing inputing space
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d\n",x,a,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've got the order of the replacements around the wrong way!

Comment: but I want to take space

Comment: @Murad replace `scanf("%s",a);` with `scanf(" %99[^\n]", a);`, it work.

Comment: @Murad You cannot ask for upvoting. If members think your question was researched before asking here and has useful info.

Comment: it's ok. I was not aware about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[30];
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]",a);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d",x,a,y);
    return 0;
}
```

This also works. The same goes here, /0 at the end adds up to the character scan and interferes. Using `fflush(stdin)` will discard any unnecessary input data including the /0.

Correct me if I am wrong as I too am a newbie at coding. :p

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%d` use `%d\n` to consume the newline, so that the following command will not just read nothing:

```
scanf("%d\n",&x);
scanf("%[^\n]",a);
scanf("%d",&y);
printf("%d\n%s\n%d",x,a,y);
```

Comment: but I want to take space