# Why can't the first string element be accessed if a limit is read using scanf() in c

Tags: c, string, scanf, gets

```
int main(){
    char str[10][50],temp[50];
    int lim,i,j;
    printf("Enter lim: ");
    scanf("%d",&lim);
    for(i=0;i<lim;++i){
        printf("Enter string[%d]: ",i+1);
        gets(str[i]);
    }
```

Here the str[0](Enter string[1]: ) can't be read. The reading starts from 'Enter string[2]: '(str[1]).

But if instead of lim, an integer is passed to loop as below, program executes correctly. What may be reason for this scenario ?

```
int main(){
    char str[10][50],temp[50];
    int lim,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;++i){
        printf("Enter string: ");
        gets(str[i]);

    }
```

Comment: `scanf` left a newline in the input stream. So the first `gets` just reads that newline. There are multiple dupes of this on SO

Comment: [may be related why-scanfd-does-not-consume-n-while-scanfc-does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275417/why-scanfd-does-not-consume-n-while-scanfc-does)

Comment: Never, never, never use `gets`. It is so insecure and so prone to exploit by buffer overrun it has been completely removed from the C library in C11. If your professor suggests uses `gets`, run, don't walk, and get a new professor -- that one does not know what he is talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scanf()` for the number has left a newline in the input stream, which will feed the first `gets()`.

Have a look here for help:
http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html
[How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)

Also, you do not want to use `gets()` anymore.
[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used?s=2|97.2434)

Comment: Not to mention it also helps remove the question from the unanswered queue so it doesn't continually cycle through.

Comment: There is no formal link, it is the category "Unanswered" from the main page. If a question is unanswered, it stays active in that queue, group, mess -- whatever you want to call it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see. And that I did know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly don't use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead. From  the manual page of `gets()`

> Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the
>   data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because
>   gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer,
>   it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer
>   security. Use fgets() instead.

Secondaly `stdin` is line buffered, when you use `scanf()` like `scanf("%d",&lim);` and press `ENTER`, the newline `\n` char is left into `stdin` stream that causes `gets()` to not to read `str[0]`.

For e.g

`for(i=0;i<lim;++i){`

```
       printf("Enter string[%d]:\n ",i);    

       fgets(str[i],sizeof(str[i]),stdin);
```

`}`

Also note that when you use `fgets()` it will store `\n` into buffer at the end. If you don't want `\n` at the end of `str[index]` you have to remove it.

Also don't Forget to check the return value of `fgets()`.

For e.g

`char *ptr = NULL;`

`ptr=fgets(str[i],sizeof(str[i]),stdin);`

```
 if( ptr != NULL && str[strlen(str[i])-1] == '\n'){

         str[strlen(str[i])-1] = '\0'; /* replace \n with \0 */
```

`}`

Comment: `scanf()` is not line buffered, `stdin` and terminal input are line buffered. Furthermore, `gets()` does read `str[0]`: it makes it en empty string precisely because there is a pending newline in `stdin`. Your proposed change does not fix the problem, the pending newline must be read manually for `fgets()` to read further input from the user.

Comment: It may also be worth explaining where the `'\n'` ends up when using `fgets` and how you may want to address removing it.

Comment: Quibble, but you should really validate the length is not zero before checking `length-1` (if the string is empty -- for whatever reason, you invoke undefined behavior). Better `size_t len = strlen (str); if (len && str[len-1] == '\n') {...}`

Comment: Yes true David.

Comment: No biggie, it's worth pointing out, I've been guilty of it on more than one occasion `:)`

Comment: Or I can suggest OP to check return value of `fgets()` as I shown `ptr!= NULL`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173197/discussion-between-achal-and-david-c-rankin).