# Different concurrency behavior in ghci and runghc

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc

I have some simple code which prints to the screen at fixed intervals of time, unless an `IORef` is set to indicate that the user is currently typing:

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
   amTyping <- newIORef False
   forkIO $ printALot amTyping
   aChar <- getChar
   writeIORef amTyping True
   aLine <- getLine
   writeIORef amTyping False
   putStrLn $ aChar : aLine
   main

printALot :: IORef Bool -> IO ()
printALot theRef = do
   putStrLn "1111111"
   threadDelay 1000000
   isTyping <- readIORef theRef
   if isTyping
      then return ()
      else printALot theRef
```

This works beautifully in GHCi, but when I use it with runghc (or compile it), the read of or write to the `IORef` seems not to work -- `printALot` just continues looping, overrunning anything the user types.

What's the difference here between ghci and runghc/compiled? Am I using `IORef`s wrong, but not noticing because ghci isn't truly multithreaded?

Comment: do you get the expected behavior if you compile with `-threaded`?

Comment: @JohnL: Yes, with or without.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with concurrency.

Your interpreted and compiled programs differ in the terminal mode they use: [non-canonical vs canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input).

In the canonical mode, your program doesn't get the character before the whole line is available — hence the effect you are observing.

To fix this, simply put the handle in the non-buffering mode:

```
import System.IO

main = do
   hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
   ...
```

Comment: Ah, bitten by line buffering again! Thanks.