# Confusion about how a getchar() loop works internally

Tags: c, io, internals, getchar

I've included an example program using `getchar()` below, for reference (not that anyone probably needs it), and feel free to address concerns with it if you desire. But my question is:

**What exactly is going on when the program calls `getchar()`**?

Here is my understanding (please clarify or correct me):

1. When getchar is called, it checks the STDIN buffer to see if there is any input.
2. If there isn't any input, getchar sleeps.
3. Upon wake, getchar checks to see if there is any input, and if not, puts it self to sleep again.
4. Steps 2 and 3 repeat until there is input.
5. Once there is input (which by convention includes an 'EOF' at the end), getchar returns the first character of this input and does *something* to indicate that the next call to getchar should return the second letter from the same buffer? I'm not really sure what that is.
6. When there are no more characters left other than EOF, does getchar flush the buffer?

The terms I used are probably not quite correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getLine(char buffer[], int maxChars);

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80

int main(void){

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int errorCode;

    errorCode = getLine(line, sizeof(line));
    if(errorCode == 1)
        printf("Input exceeded maximum line length of %d characters.\n", MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    printf("%s\n", line);

    return 0;

}

int getLine(char buffer[], int maxChars){
    int c, i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < maxChars - 1)
        buffer[i++] = c;
    buffer[i++] = '\0';
    if(i == maxChars)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would keep calling `getchar` until it returns EOF. At that point, it's the end of input so there shouldn't be anything left in the buffer to flush. Characters will "buffer" from the standard input until an EOF (ctrl-D) or newline (LF) is seen, then it will provide all the characters in the buffer plus the special character (EOF or LF).

Comment: I see... so each call to `getchar` removes a character from the buffer (if there is one)?

Comment: Yes. Each `getchar` retrieves one character. As Jonathan points out in his answer, I should be clear the EOF isn't a character but a `-1` value (`int`) to indicate that an end of input is reached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 2-4 are slightly off.

If there is no input in the standard I/O buffer, `getchar()` calls a function to reload the buffer.  On a Unix-like system, that normally ends up calling the `read()` system call, and the `read()` system call puts the process to sleep until there is input to be processed, or the kernel knows there will be no input to be processed (EOF).  When the read returns, the code adjusts the data structures so that `getchar()` knows how much data is available.  You description implies polling; the standard I/O system does not poll for input.

Step 5 uses the adjusted pointers to return the correct values.

There really isn't an EOF character; it is a state, not a character.  Even though you type <kbd>Control-D</kbd> or <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> to indicate 'EOF', that character is not inserted into the input stream.  In fact, those characters cause the system to flush any typed characters that are still waiting for 'line editing' operations (like backspace) to change them so that they are made available to the `read()` system call.  If there are no such characters, then `read()` returns 0 as the number of available characters, which means EOF.  Then `getchar()` returns the value `EOF` (usually `-1` but guaranteed to be negative whereas valid characters are guaranteed to be non-negative (zero or positive)).

> So basically, rather than polling, is it that hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> causes a certain I/O interrupt, and then when the OS receives this, it wakes up any processes that are sleeping for I/O?

Yes, hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> triggers interrupts and the OS kernel processes them and wakes up processes that are waiting for the data.  The terminal driver is woken by the kernel when interrupt occurs, and decides what to do with the character(s) that were just received. They may be stashed for further processing (canonical mode) or made available immediately (raw mode), etc.  Assuming, of course, that the input is a terminal; if the input is from a disk file, it is simpler in many ways — or if it is a pipe, or …

Nominally, it isn't the terminal app that gets woken by the interrupt; it is the kernel that wakes first, then the shell running in the terminal app that is woken because there's data for it to read, and only when there's output does the terminal app get woken.

I say 'nominally' because there's an outside chance that in fact the terminal app does mediate the I/O via a pty (pseudo-tty), but I think it happens at the kernel level and the terminal application is involved fairly late in the process.  There's a huge disconnect really between the keyboard where you type and the display where what you type appears.

See also [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/358381#358381).

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I was hoping for an answer like this. So basically, rather than polling, is it that hitting return causes a certain I/O interrupt, and then when the OS receives this, it wakes up any processes that are sleeping for I/O? EDIT: Or rather, when the terminal app gets the return pressed, it sends a (software) interrupt to its child process? (I'm a little fuzzy on processes, so I'm probably not saying this well.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information in the edit and the link. You're a very good writer.