# getchar() loops over EOF when STDIN provided through a pipe

Tags: c, loops, pipe, stdin, getchar

I'm in front of something I can't explain. There is no better way of explaining than giving an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char c;
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%x\n", c);
    }
   return(0);
}
```

If I execute this command, it just iterates indefinitely this way:

```
$ echo -n "A" | ./binary
41
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
...
```

From what I know and what I read ([Confusion about how a getchar() loop works internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444932/confusion-about-how-a-getchar-loop-works-internally)), I thought `echo -n "A"` would send a `A` to **stdin** and then trigger an EOF *event* (I'm not sure what EOF really is) **once**, thus my loop would iterate twice at most, and then would sleep waiting for a new input in **stdin**.

But no, it iterates over EOF, and I don't understand why.

I ran this command to try to understand :

```
$ echo -n "A" | strace ./binary
read(0, "A", 4096)                      = 1
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7ff6000
write(1, "41\n", 341
)                     = 3
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
write(1, "ffffffff\n", 9ffffffff
)               = 9
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
write(1, "ffffffff\n", 9ffffffff
)               = 9
...
```

So it appears read() is reading nothing, and returns 0, which is interpreted by getchar() as EOF. But why, oh why does it iterate like this, whereas when I execute this binary the normal way, it works as expected :

```
$ ./binary
A
41
a
B
42
a
^C
$
```

(Above output could be a bit confusing, but when I entered <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>, I sent `A` then `\n` (0x0a) to stdin, so the binary just displays these in their hexa representations ,`41` and `a`)

Could someone explain this to me ? What did I miss ?

Thanks a lot for reading !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you encounter `EOF`, `getchar` will return immediately with return value `EOF`. The stream pointer for the stream will not advance, it will stay on the EOF marker. Subsequent calls to `getchar` will also return immediately, since the stream is still at the `EOF` marker.

Note that this differs from the behaviour when `stdin` is attached to an input device. In that case, `getchar` will pause, waiting for further input if the input buffer is empty. `getchar`will not return `EOF` until an `EOF` is sent from the input device (`CTRL-D` sends `EOF` from a keyboard in Linux).

Comment: Ok that's helpful ! Thanks for that answer, accepted :)

Comment: `char c` will never compare equal to `EOF` if `char` is unsigned. And it will equal `EOF` if `char` is signed for certain non-ASCII chars (those which will produce the corresponding negative value as `EOF`).

Answer (score 5):

getchar() returns an int, not a char. The larger return value allows you to look for a return value EOF, which is -1. This is the return value for errors and end of file. Changing the type of c to int will not change the behavior of printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int c;
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        if ( c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%x\n", c);
    }
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this precision

Answer (score 2):

First,   EOF is -1 which is 0xFFFFFFFF.

the system function 'getchar()' returns an int, not a char.

So to make any comparison,  'c' must be an int, not a char.

Now, to exit a while loop, there must be a comparison to some condition that must be true to continue in the loop.

suggest using the following code model.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )  //<< for main, better to use 'void' rather than empty braces
{
    int c; //<< because getchar() returns an int, not a char

    // following loop has EOF as exit condition
    // note in C, && is lower presidence than = and != so is evaluated last
    // note in C, && is evaluated from left to right
    // note to help the compiler to catch errors,
    //      always place the literal on the left of a comparison
    while (c = getchar() && EOF != c) 
    {
        printf("%x\n", c);
    }
   return(0);
} // end function: main
```