# Why does cin need newline to be entered?

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
char ch;
while(cin.get(ch))
{
    std::cerr<<"got ch:"<<ch<<std::endl;
}
```

Why do I have to hit enter before the "got ch:" is printed on screen ?

Is there a way to have characters echoed right after they are typed ?

Answer (score 5):

See [Canonical vs Non-canonical Terminal Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/358381#358381) for a lot of details.

Yes, by default you have to enter return before any data is made available.

Yes, there are ways to use non-canonical input so that characters are available as soon as they are entered.  However, the mechanisms for obtaining that behaviour are radically different between Windows and Unix-based systems.