# What is maximum length of character Array which can be taken as input in C++?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[100000];
    cin>>s;
    cout<<strlen(s);
    return 0;   
 }
```

In this Program,character array takes input upto length 4095.
Bigger than this length it does not take input.
Please provide reason for this problem.

Comment: Your stack is probably to small to allocate such big char array. Use `std::string` and `getline()` to get _unlimited_ sized input.

Comment: Not strictly unlimited.   There is an upper limit that depends on available memory (which may be physical, virtual, and/or subject to system quotas), how memory is addressed (e.g. 32-bit vs 64 bit), how memory is allocated (`std::string` requests memory from an allocator, and different allocators use different allocation strategies).   All of those factors, and more, interact  .....

Comment: I used     getline()  but it create same problem

Comment: How are you generating the standard input?  Can you prove it's not terminating after 4k, or containing whitespace?  You do realise the `>>` reads whitespace-delimited values, don't you?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [Read a string of length greater than 4096 bytes from stdin in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886167/read-a-string-of-length-greater-than-4096-bytes-from-stdin-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `char s[MAX_SIZE]` locally, then it gets stored in the `stack` area, which has limited amount of memory associated with it.

But, if you declare it `globally`, then it's size can be increased nearly to the remaining memory left in your PC. or use `std::string` instead to get rid of *MAX_SIZE* issue.

Comment: You should get some sort of stack overflow error from this, not have the program work but just read partial input (or is a stack overflow undefined behaviour?).

Comment: @Dukeling a stack overflow *is* undefined behaviour.

Comment: Either way, [the post I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886167/read-a-string-of-length-greater-than-4096-bytes-from-stdin-in-c) in a comment on the question points out a more likely root cause for this.

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to find proof one way or the other, but didn't have much luck. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Dukeling now that I think of it, a stack overflow probably isn't formally UB, because the Standard does not define what a "stack" is. In practice, it is : a stack overflow just overwrites whatever is there. It may thrash your heap, some other memory, or fall off of your process' address space and segfault.