# How does an 'enter' input work while running putchar() function in C?

Tags: c, putchar

I tested this code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 main()
  4 {
  5     int c;
  6 
  7     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  8         putchar(c);
  9         printf("%d ", c);
 10     }
 11     printf("%d\n", c);
 12 }
```

Question:

When I inputted a line of characters, and then inputted an 'enter', I got this kind of result:

```
asdf

a97 s115 d100 f102
```

When I added an EOF(ctrl+d) directly behind a line of characters, I got the result directly behind the input, like:

```
asdfa97 s115 d100 f102
```

My questions are whether the 'enter' triggered the code running? Why when I input an EOF, was not the 'enter' needed to output the result? Why did I need another EOF to quit running?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your terminal adds EOF when you submit a line.

Comment: Buffered input. What you write is not actually consumed by `getchar()` until you hit return or feed it an `EOF`. When you hit return, the console simply moves the cursor to the next line, whereas with `EOF` it doesn't. That's just it.

Comment: I think you're not including all of the output.  I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Quentin and Filipe - OP's terminal is almost certainly not sending EOF in *either* case.

Comment: Very closely related to [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first case, are you sure the output wasn't:

```
asdf
a97 s115 d100 f102 
10
```

That is, your input line `asdf` followed on the next line by the output characters and numbers for `'a'`, `'s'`, `'d'`, and `'f'`, and then *another* line (because you `putchar()` the newline character, too) with a `10` (the ASCII value for a newline character) on it?

Note that your program doesn't exit at this point either - it's still waiting for more input.

^D is *not* inputting an EOF "character", either.  It's just sending a signal to your terminal program.  In your case, it looks like it means "flush buffers", so your program gets access to the terminal's line-buffered input of `"asdf"`.  Since your program doesn't output a newline, you get the output on the same line.

If you enter the `^D` *on a line by itself*, you'll cause the terminal to close its connection to your program and the actual `EOF` will come through, terminating your progam.

Example - input "asdf\n":

```
# ./example 
asdf
a97 s115 d100 f102 
10
```

Example - input "asdf^D":

```
$ ./example 
asdfa97 s115 d100 f102
```

Example - input "asdf\n^D":

```
$ ./example 
asdf
a97 s115 d100 f102 
10 -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, there is an output '10'. I appreciate that you also help me understand the '10' output:)

Comment: Every time the putchar() is called, there will be a new line, right? For example, if there are three putchar(), the '10' will appear in the third line counted from the result line?

Comment: The `10` is the ASCII value for the newline character you typed.  It gets output exactly the same as all your other input does, it's just that you can't see the newline - it makes a new line, after all.

Comment: And no, there will not be a new line each time `putchar()` is called.  If you pass it a newline character, it will output a newline character, but it won't add any extra ones in for you.