# C++ linux read continuously string and detect backspace key

Tags: c++, linux, string

i would like to know if there is a way to read a string continuously on the console and detect the backspace key if the user erase a character. Let me explain a little bit more, for example:

1. Write a word on the console: "Word" So i got the string. And i can use all the methods from string like access to the characters item[0] = "W"  or item.length()
2. The user press the backspace key and know my string item will have "Wor"
3. If the user put another letter the string is updated "Worrtw"

I using this for recommend words according what user is typing. I posting this beacause i really don't found anything usefull at the moment for the keywords or something about the string.

Comment: You'll need to look up [canonical and non-canonical terminal I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input/358381#358381) — and perhaps libraries that help support it, such as the `ncurses` library.

Comment: A second suggestion for `ncurses`. But you're not going to have fun ;).

Comment: Well i should take a look on that "funny" library then. Thanks