# Windows C++ program not outputting all std::cout after Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, g++, cout, mingw-w64

I have g++ installed on Windows 10 with MinGW-w64, and when I run a program with an infinite loop and then I stop it with Ctrl+C, it only outputs the first std::cout after the loop. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n;
    while (cin>>n);
    cout<<n*2<<"."<<n*3<<"."<<n*4<<endl;
}
```

If I input `25` in the console and stop it with Ctrl+C, it outputs `50`. But if I build the same program on my Ubuntu machine, input also `25` and exit the loop with Ctrl+D it outputs `50.75.100`. Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: `CTRL-C` and `CTRL-D` do totally different things. The Windows equivalent of your Linux systems `CTRL-D` is `CTRL-Z`.

Comment: Thanks! It waz CTRL-Z but you have to press ENTER after that, which is not needed in CTRL-C. Now it's working.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759979/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001734/