# Exit read listening when pressing "Ctrl + c" in C

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, ctrl

I'm rewriting a shell in C and I fell on a problem.

When writing a command — for example `echo "this` — we got a new prompt ("dquote>", in zsh) and we can exit it with "Ctrl + c" and get back to our last command prompt.

I'm stuck there; I just can't get out of my read function (listen on "dquote>"), I tried to write on stdout an EOF when pressing "ctrl + c" but it doesn't read it.

I switched to non-canonical mode.
I catch signal with `signal(SIGINT, sig_hand);`

then i execute this part of code when signal is catched:

```
static void sig_hand(int sig)
{
    if (g_shell.is_listen_bracket) // if is the first prompt or no
        putchar(4); // EOT
    else
    {
        putstr("\n");
        print_prompt();
    }
}
```

and my read function:

```
int     j;
char    command[ARG_MAX];
char    buff[3];

j = -1;
while (1)
{
    bzero(buff, 3);
    read(0, buff, 3);
    if (buff[0] == 4 && !buff[1] && !buff[2])
        return (ctrl_d(shell));
    else if (isprint(buff[0]) && !buff[1] && !buff[2]) // if is between 32 and 126 (ascii)
    {
        command[++j] = buff[0];
        putchar(buff[0]);
    }
}
command[++j] = '\0';
return (strdup(command));
```

So my code waiting on "read(0, buff, 3);", and i want to quit it when pressing ctrl + c.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: `man siglongjmp`

Comment: thanks for your reply but is a school projet and this function is not allowed.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is since you've not shown any code or discussed whether you manipulate signal handling or terminal settings in your shell.  You might find [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/) helpful, or it might be a red-herring.  You should discuss (better, show) how your shell is handling signals.  Control-C should generate a SIGINT; if your shell is ignoring that, or mishandling it, it might account for your trouble.

Comment: Well, technically it is not a function, though it appears to be.

Comment: I edited my question. (Ctrl + d work well)

Comment: If Ctrl+D *works well*, you must be running on DOS/Windows.

Comment: Note: `read(0, buff, 3)` can return {-1,0,1,2, or 3} Handle all cases. Also: `command[++j] = buff[0];` should *al least* be `command[j++] = buff[0];` (plus you may want to loop on 'j' upto the return value you got from `read()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of `EOF` as a character that you can '*print to `stdout`*', it is a state that the file handle can be in, and it implies that there is no more data coming. To put your `stdout` into the `EOF` state, you would have to call `close()` - which is most likely not what you want.

Watch out - `0x04` is actually `EOT`, End of Transmission.

In any case, why do you want to send `EOT` to the `stdout` of your application? If this behaved the way it would appear you think it does, then the terminal emulator (or whatever is connected to your stdout) would quit - not your shell, and it certainly wouldn't revert your shell from the '*waiting for more input*' state to the '*waiting for input*' state.

You need to handle the `^C` in the signal handler, and adjust your shell's state appropriately, getting it to abandon the current input mode and redraw the basic prompt.

---

**Edit:** What you need to remember is that your 'shell' is writing text (output) and control characters to the terminal emulator - the terminal emulator is writing text (input) and control characters to your 'shell'.

If you want to revert the prompt from `dquote>` to `mysh$`, then *you* must update the terminal by writing a new prompt to it.

To keep track of what you are currently doing, it might make most sense to use the [State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) approach. You might have a handful of states, including:

1. `INPUT_WAITING`
2. `INPUT_WAITING_CONT`
3. `COMMAND_RUN`

When in the `INPUT_WAITING` state, you would print the `mysh$` prompt, and handle input.
When a newline is received, you would then decide '*do we have all of the information?*' before advancing to the `INPUT_WAITING_CONT` state if not, or the `COMMAND_RUN` state if you do.

The  `INPUT_WAIT_CONT` state would printout the `dquote>` prompt, and take similar actions... *'do we have enough information?*' Yes: `COMMAND_RUN`, No: `INPUT_WAIT_CONT`.

It's then up to you to revert to the `INPUT_WAIT` state and redraw the `mysh$` prompt when the user presses `^C`, or when the command execution has completed.

Comment: I confused EOF and EOT sorry. Ctrl + d send a EOT which is read by `read` function. So I was thinking if i can write an EOT, `read` would read it and i could treat it properly like `^C`. "to abandon the current input" how ? That my question.

Comment: `Ctrl + d send a EOT which is read by read function` Not on UNIX. Normally, ^D is handled by the terminal driver (and translated into an EOF *event*) , the 0x04 is never seen by the reading program.