# What happens when I enter EOF while using cin in C++?

Tags: c++

I entered three inputs to the code below and got the results as follows

(1)

input: <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>

result: (blank)

(2)

input: abc<kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>

result: (not terminated yet)

(3)

input: abc

result: abc

```
using namespace::std;

int main()
{

  string input;

  cin >> input;
  cout << input << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

**I wonder why I should enter EOF twice to terminate the code in the second case
not just only one time like the first case (it terminated immediately)**

Comment: This behaviour is terminal-specific. AFAIK, some terminals only send EOF if you press Ctrl-D on an empty line.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  In this question, EOF means ctrl+D, sorry for confussion

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to render keys, you can use `<key>CTRL+D</key>` in the markdown.

Comment: Hmm, apparently that's no longer possible. Anyways it's clearer like this.

Comment: @molbdnilo I pressed Ctrl-D after abc in second case. but the program was not terminated immediately. Why this happen?

Comment: @고9마 As they mentioned, that's terminal specific behavior.

Comment: @고9마 Probably because of the reason in my first comment. (C++ has nothing to do with it.) You need to consult the documentation for your terminal.

Comment: @고9마 Ah, I forgot the exact tag, it's `<kbd>xxx</kbd>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical vs. non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input)