# Why does a call to read() hang waiting for a newline (C)?

Tags: c, terminal, io, posix, termios

Consider this program (a basic implementation of `cat`):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[4096];
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  while ( ( bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof buffer) ) > 0) {
    ssize_t bytes_written = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bytes_read);
    if (bytes_written == -1) return errno;
    assert(bytes_read == bytes_written);
  }
  if (bytes_read == -1) return errno;
  assert(bytes_read == 0);
  return 0;
}
```

I was wondering why this hangs waiting for `read(2)` input to be terminated with a `\n`, when I didn't specify something like `readline()`.

My initial assumption for `read` was that it would return `0` whenever input wasn't available and the associated file descriptor open, and `-1` (a common representation for `EOF`) when it was closed, and perhaps another negative integer for error.

After reading the manual, and writing the program, I was under the impression that `read(2)` would block until any input was available with size >0 and immediately return with that information; however, it seems the terminal causes it to block until it receives a `\n` character.

My question is: Why does this not adhere to my expectations, and what is really happening here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `read(2)`, it's the terminal driver. It allows you to edit your input and doesn't make the data available until you type Return or Ctl-d.

Comment: Notice that it doesn't happen when reading from a file or pipe, or when the terminal is in raw mode.

Comment: Input can be unbuffered, block buffered or line buffered.  See the man page for `setvbuf`.  Your terminal is set to line buffered.

Comment: @stark `setvbuf()` does not apply to file-descriptor-based calls such as `read()`, only `FILE *`-based streams calls.

Comment: Using `assert()` for error checking is not a good idea.  First, `assert()` is a no-op if compiled with `NDEBUG`, and you can't control how your code will be compiled in the future.  Second, aborting the entire process is usually an **extreme** overreaction - programs are written in the real-world to do things, and in the real world things go wrong.  Just about the worst thing a real-world program designed to actually do something can do when something like unexpected input is received is to give up, abort, and drop core.

Comment: `assert()` is intended to detect logic errors when debugging, not runtime errors that can actually occur in production.

Comment: This is canonical mode of PTY.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Canonical vs. non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/358342/12149471)

Comment: So awhat is exactly happening with `read()`? Is the program in a blocked state until the terminal receives a new line?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912796/12149471) for an example of how to turn off canonical mode.

Comment: I have the same question as @user8393252